# Slow insert of one specific row in FTS3 table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, full-text-search

I've got one Full-text-search table table created as:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE library_search  
                USING fts3 (
                [...]
```

the table has a total of 15 columns, only text columns.

The problem happens when I insert into the table.
Most inserts are done quickly (less than half a second). However, when I the table has about 2100 - 2200 rows, there is one insert that takes ages, about 60 seconds to complete.

I have observed the following:

- this happens when the row inserted is about the 2100th - 2200th one.
- if the data set inserted is identical, it will always be the same row.
- if the data set changes, the row is different, but it will always be around 2100 - 2200.
- this happens in all the devices i've tested with (Android 4.2+)
- when this happens, the inserted row has nothing special in it... the size of it's content values are standard.
- this happens either if the insertions are done with an immediate transaction, an exclusive transaction or not transaction at all.
- when this happens, the DB is about 15Mb big.

I have no idea why is this happening. The only thing I can suspect, is that when that specific insertion is done, the size of the database is such that the db manager has to perform some special operation, such as allocating more space in the file system or something alike...

I would appreciate any ideas. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please note FTS tables store only text values, and cannot have an explicit autoincrementing column (use the `docid` instead). For 'normal' data, you must use a normal table.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the table has only text columns and no autoincrement. I just editted the table definition after copy-pasting to simplify the question. I am using a FTS table because I need to implement a search feature that needs using MATCH in the WHERE clause.